# how to call viewForHeaderInSection outside its delegate call

Tags: ios, objective-c

My problem is that i want to call `viewForHeaderInSection` "UITableView delegate Method" from outside its delegation call. I have addObserver method in which i want to call again `viewForHeaderInSection` with `Objective c`. And will it be called with loop counted with sections?.

Your work will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table view is designed so that it will call your data source for data as it needs them. It is done this way to greatly improve performance and reduce memory footprint on large data sets.

You can not force the table view to call any of the data source methods. You may call one of the reload methods though, for instance `reloadData` should do. But there is still a catch here. Reload will only call the data source method if it needs to. In the given case the header must actually be visible. It will not be called if for instance user has scrolled the header off the screen.

If this is enough for you then simply call `reloadData`. If not then you have loads of details to add to your question. What exactly are you doing, what is your goal, what is your current result and what expected, what are the edge cases you may expect...

Comment: yep i think reload is the final solution.